# Wordpress Archive page completely blank

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following archive page setup:

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
        </ul>

        <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
        <ul>
             <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, the page is completely white when I load the archive page. It is a new site with no plugins, and all the other pages are working fine. Any idea?

Comment: wp_get_archives() wants an array of key => value pairs (like 'type'=> 'monthly')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weird reason, the archive became visible when i added the code to the index.php file.